# Display a large amount of text dependant on value incoming

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a program for iOS using Swift 3. I have the the thing working so that when a button is pressed it outputs a number, and then text shows in the label.

But the text is quite a lot, and there will be 10 variations of it.  Is there a better way of doing it rather than in the VC, maybe an XML file maybe or 10?

I know it is messy, to put it in a `UIViewController` subclass, and don't like the idea of that.

```
func infoArea () {

    if step == 1 {

        infoBox.text = "The purpose of this track - in a nutshell: Stop eating foods which pile on the pounds. Develop less desire for fattening and unhealthy foods and drinks.\n \n \nSlim for Life - Step 1: Less Desire \n \n \nWhile listening you'll experience: \n \n • A deeply therapeutic meditative process \n • A feeling of whole mind and body relaxation \n • An opportunity to embrace change and become totally focused on releasing excess weight \n • The ability to develop less desire for foods and drinks that do you harm and more desire for those that do you good \n • A chance to take control as you recognise that this is not another diet \n • A life-changing experience! \n \n \nAfterwards and with repeated listening you'll experience: \n \n • Feelings of calm, inner peace and a greater sense of security \n • Less mind chatter and more clarity as you take control of your thoughts \n • Feelings of not fancying unhealthy and fattening foods and drinks \n • Wondering if your taste buds are changing as you no longer enjoy sweet things \n • An ability to comfortably ignore snacks, sweets and junk foods \n • Determination to succeed \n • Increased energy levels as you develop the habits of a naturally slim person \n • Improved health as you’re sleeping better and feeling more nourished from sleep \n • A gentle connection between your mind and your body that promotes healing \n • More self-confidence \n \n \n \nPermanent weight release is something you have been keeping from happening. \nWhether your thoughts and feelings about yourself are good or bad, they will return to you as automatically as an echo. \nBe sure to send yourself only good, strong, positive thoughts, feelings and emotions. \n \nLearn to love yourself."

        let range = NSMakeRange(0, 152)
        let range2 = NSMakeRange(193, 1470)
        infoBox.attributedText = attributedString(from: infoBox.text, nonBoldRange: range, nonBoldRange2: range2)


    } else if step == 2 {
        infoBox.text = "This is going to be information number 2"

    } else if step == 3 {
        infoBox.text = "this will be number 3"
```

Comment: where do you get the values of `step` ?

Comment: The step comes from a different View controller, i have 10 buttons and each button has a value it assigns to step, then in 2 other New controllers the step value is used to show a specific text and on another controller load the correct music file to play. All that works great. i just thought it was messy to have over 1000 lines of text in a view controller for each step so that would come to around 10,000 lines of text for all 10 steps before the code is even added in

Comment: yes, makes sense. there are two solutions below, pick one, or master the solutions, and combine them ;)

Comment: Cheers, Yes I have taken the code below and used that it was a good way of removing the text from the code, keeping them separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply store your text in a more convenient way, even if it is long text, i would not recommend to use `XML`, nor 10 different `XML`'s.

Lets just create a little helper struct, what will hold a static `String` type `Array`, and lets get all the stuff from there by accessing in at the right index. However, you can declare `texts` variable on your `UIViewController` subclass, it causes no big harm.

```
struct DisplayableContents {
    static let texts: [String] = [
    "first long text",
    "second long text",
    "third long text",
    "etc..."
    ]
}
```

And you can use it in your `UIViewController` subclass the following way:

```
func infoArea () {
  infoBox.text = DisplayableContents.texts[step]
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me, I'd rather have the Information text separate from my code, that way I don't get lost in all the text. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it using a plist to contain "step" information (which you can then use as a dictionary).  for each step I had a "description" entry in the plist for short descriptions and a fileName entry for longer ones.   I wrapped up this plist/dictionary in a little class that would return the attributes and, if necessary get the file content (which is part of the project's files in my case).